# How does the rails connection pooling work?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, connection

I'm running a rails 2.3.5 application, which supports me to pool mysql connections to my database. But I remember reading that my mongrel servers are single threaded. What's the point of having a connection pool, to a single threaded application? Is there a way to multi-thread my app?

Also, do connection pools understand, that ruby 1.8 has "green" threads?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

**Manage Connections**

The major benefit of connection pooling for a single-thread server like Mongrel/Passenger/etc is that the connection is established/maintained in a Rack handler outside the main Rails request processing.  This allows for a connection to be established once vs. many times as it's used in different ways.  The goal is to re-use the established connection and minimize the number of connections.  This should prevent having to reconnect within a given request processing cycle and possibly even between requests (if I recall correctly).

**Multiple Concurrent Connections**

Although most use cases (Mongrel/Passenger) are single threaded and can only use a single connection at a time - there is JRuby and environments/app servers that have full multi-threaded support.  Rails has been thread safe since 2.2

**TL;DR:**

Pool establishes connection automatically.  Some people do use multiple concurrent db connections from pool.

Comment: Does that mean that if I have 150 max_connections in mysql config that each connection in the pool rails creates will consume one of these connections for max of 150?

In other words, if my app is the only one using the DB can I set the pool in database.yml to equal the number of max_connections?

Comment: That would only be true if you have one instance of your app.  If you had a Passenger server with 20 workers, each one could potentially consume up to the max pool size.

Comment: Yes, worst case you want to ensure pool_size * num_workers <= max_connections.  In the average case you will consume num_workers connections.